# Show that if the product (the composite) of two linear operators exist, it is linear

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am given this problem to consider and I am unsure how to prove it. It would be nice to see a definition for what it means to be linear or how to check if something is linear because I don't know what that means. I found a solution for the sum but I am unsure how to prove the product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear function is a function $f$ so that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ for any vectors $u$ and $v$ and $f(av)=af(v)$ for any scalar $a$ and any vector $v$.

To prove what you want, just write it out and see what happens.  For example (sums), suppose that $f$ and $g$ are linear and that $u$ and $v$ are any vectors and $a$ is a scalar.

$(f+g)(u+v) = f(u+v)+g(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)+g(u)+g(v)=(f(u)+g(u))+(f(v)+g(v))=(f+g)(u) + (f+g)(v)$.

You can make a similar argument with the scalar.  This shows that if $f$ and $g$ are linear functions, then $f+g$ is a linear function.

You have to be careful with the product.  $f\cdot g$ will not be linear, but $f\circ g$ will be linear (product is $\cdot$, composition is $\circ$).  The method is the same though.

$(f\circ g)(u+v)=f(g(u+v))=f(g(u)+g(v))=...$ (fill in the rest).  Then do the same thing for the scalar.

Answer (score 0):

We say that a function $A:V \rightarrow W$ between two vector spaces (any space where we may add and scale by real or complex numbers) is linear if
$$
A(v_1+v_2) = Av_1 + Av_2
$$
and 
$$
A(\lambda v) =\lambda Av
$$
for any $v,v_1,...$. To check that something is linear, we need only check these conditions.

To show that the composition of two linear operators is Suppose that $A: V\rightarrow W$ and $B: W \rightarrow X$ are linear. Then for any $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $V$ we have that
$$
BA(v_1 + v_2) = B(Av_1 + Av_2) = BAv_1 + BAv_2,
$$
since both $A$ and $B$ are linear. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is in the field of scalars, then
$$
BA(\lambda v_1) = B(\lambda Av_1) = \lambda BAv_1.
$$
Therefore, $BA$ will always be linear.

If by linear operator you mean a continuous linear operator on some normed vector space, the above also shows that $BA$ is continuous, since the composition of continuous functions is continuous.